# Wifi error in hotel multiple floor hotel case

Tags: wireless, 22.04

I'm experiencing an issue with my WiFi. I'm staying in a hotel that spans several floors, thus there are many different access points, all under the same network name. The problem is that after initially connecting on the first floor, now when I try to connect from other floors, my computer fails to connect despite having sufficient signal strength. My other devices running Android or Windows do not have this problem.

Using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.